# Does jmeter clustering works with private ips

Tags: jmeter

Does jmeter clustering works with private ips.  We are planning jmeter cluster with elastic beanstalk in aws,  as observed the machines created by using Terra form giving private ips and as per docs available on net says to work in jmeter cluster we should have public ips.  Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you mean the master/slaves setup for JMeter by "cluster".

Then, there are mentions that in case of private nets master & slaves must be on same physical network.

*Though I personally found no explanation/justification for claims like that in RMI references - but whatever.*

That can't be guaranteed in AWS.

What apparently works - is tunneling. There are couple of docs on the subject over the Net, [here's one example](http://www.testingdiaries.com/jmeter-on-aws/).